# Replacing subject ID with part of filename in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, gsub

I have the following dataset (which this is a subset of):

```
list(structure(list(V1 = c(5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L), V7 = 1:42, V8 = c("D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", 
"I", "D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", 
"D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", "D", 
"D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I"), V9 = c("P", "P", "P", 
"N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "T", "T", "T", "N", 
"N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", 
"N", "T", "T", "T", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P"
), V10 = c("5480.jpg", "8186.jpg", "5621.jpg", "9471.jpg", "9007.jpg", 
"6555.jpg", "7280.jpg", "4622.jpg", "5594.jpg", "2688.jpg", "9330.jpg", 
"6834.jpg", "7705.jpg", "7080.jpg", "7233.jpg", "2700.jpg", "9430.jpg", 
"9342.jpg", "8161.jpg", "8501.jpg", "2224.jpg", "7380.jpg", "9592.jpg", 
"9341.jpg", "8193.jpg", "4180.jpg", "1510.jpg", "9611.jpg", "6831.jpg", 
"2710.jpg", "2393.jpg", "2840.jpg", "7179.jpg", "7580.jpg", "5460.jpg", 
"1721.jpg", "9400.jpg", "3400.jpg", "6830.jpg", "1650.jpg", "7480.jpg", 
"8170.jpg"), V11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), V12 = c(1987.49322676, 2003.78750029, 2016.18643522, 2029.98508547, 
2046.082619, 2059.69678371, 2072.27662962, 2088.35319136, 2103.33510062, 
2114.53590582, 2130.63408597, 2143.73122899, 2156.81204578, 2172.88432076, 
2186.75108144, 2199.0348313, 2215.13425956, 2227.83303149, 2241.3301239, 
2257.42777441, 2271.80813707, 2283.5826768, 2299.68353984, 2312.48300952, 
2325.8857002, 2341.97929395, 2355.55967609, 2368.15728052, 2384.22079626, 
2398.39871977, 2410.39828415, 2426.49730549, 2441.29442761, 2452.69164213, 
2468.77255819, 2483.74729774, 2494.91740773, 2511.01324173, 2524.71353057, 
2537.21073726, 2553.29676658, 2565.76299181), V13 = c(1992.50788501, 
2005.10323553, 2018.90335157, 2035.00063673, 2048.59856263, 2061.21330913, 
2077.2857765, 2092.26887412, 2103.45229051, 2119.55267144, 2132.6498404, 
2145.74762995, 2161.82758365, 2175.69277904, 2187.96811315, 2204.05114602, 
2216.75108264, 2230.24948894, 2246.34679858, 2260.74340724, 2272.51665986, 
2288.60037167, 2301.39998537, 2314.79927424, 2330.89755634, 2344.49464516, 
2357.09652349, 2373.16490066, 2387.3319872, 2399.31499871, 2415.4143731, 
2430.21259702, 2441.6115735, 2457.70809613, 2472.68103695, 2483.85340637, 
2499.93071796, 2513.63010047, 2526.12895945, 2542.22682022, 2554.70658186, 
2568.37009562), V14 = c(1993.75330082, 2006.15330628, 2019.95320617, 
2036.0504665, 2049.66527255, 2062.25314096, 2078.33594597, 2093.30683345, 
2104.50289596, 2120.60234076, 2133.69945801, 2146.7972698, 2162.86761203, 
2176.7348525, 2189.01761019, 2205.10166161, 2217.80139939, 2231.29901038, 
2247.39608311, 2261.79325268, 2273.55805641, 2289.6500982, 2302.4502089, 
2315.84985489, 2331.94791451, 2345.5321581, 2358.14292019, 2374.20631859, 
2388.37072667, 2400.36479062, 2416.46512504, 2431.26296093, 2442.66090881, 
2458.75766914, 2473.73112172, 2484.89661205, 2500.98045728, 2514.68023375, 
2527.17905154, 2543.27528682, 2555.74530719, 2569.41290119), 
    V15 = c(1999.77091881, 2012.17069799, 2025.96958909, 2042.06618575, 
    2055.68091664, 2068.26119022, 2084.34226467, 2099.31945827, 
    2110.51916708, 2126.61785271, 2139.71493787, 2152.80164663, 
    2168.87694609, 2182.74020292, 2195.02198667, 2211.11792771, 
    2223.81686668, 2237.31428137, 2253.41109216, 2267.80013181, 
    2279.56734828, 2295.66662992, 2308.46672665, 2321.86612209, 
    2337.96326175, 2351.54361379, 2364.1484122, 2380.21542344, 
    2394.38206849, 2406.38124464, 2422.48059629, 2437.27845236, 
    2448.6762584, 2464.76403815, 2479.73784862, 2490.90240349, 
    2506.99697921, 2520.6965112, 2533.19453821, 2549.27967288, 
    2561.75640359, 2575.41968263), V16 = c(1.97612254, 1.22228754, 
    1.07244078, 0.97520718, 1.01181801, 2.26757398, 1.69456861, 
    1.50956233, 0.94663342, 1.92908233, 1.00595454, 1.0762747, 
    1.43612961, 1.27413358, 1.12314117, 1.99375197, 0.76091358, 
    1.3039465, 0.90283654, 2.19145332, 0.79318283, 1.19297502, 
    0.69679878, 2.89059776, 1.02289159, 2.2764881, 1.6335375, 
    1.66840243, 1.11664701, 0.73965987, 1.32531222, 9, 0.94261183, 
    3.38459728, 2.31628939, 1.40065909, 1.38189958, 2.51368216, 
    3.20556865, 1.36864499, 0.77406087, 1.38290615), V17 = c(5, 
    1.3, 2.7, 5, 2.5, 1.5, 5, 3.9, 0.1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2.8, 1.2, 
    5, 1.6, 2.4, 5, 3.3, 0.7, 5, 1.7, 2.3, 5, 2.5, 1.5, 5, 3.1, 
    0.9, 5, 3.7, 0.3, 5, 3.9, 0.1, 5, 2.6, 1.4, 5, 1.4, 2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L)), structure(list(V1 = c(5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 
5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 
5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 
5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 
5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 5002L, 
5002L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L), V7 = 1:42, V8 = c("D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", 
"I", "D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", 
"D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", "D", 
"D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I"), V9 = c("P", "P", "P", 
"N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "T", "T", "T", "N", 
"N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", 
"N", "T", "T", "T", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P"
), V10 = c("4680.jpg", "8341.jpg", "5820.jpg", "9620.jpg", "9042.jpg", 
"6250.jpg", "7260.jpg", "4607.jpg", "5000.jpg", "2053.jpg", "9320.jpg", 
"6821.jpg", "7950.jpg", "7035.jpg", "7090.jpg", "2490.jpg", "9530.jpg", 
"9432.jpg", "8180.jpg", "8496.jpg", "2310.jpg", "9001.jpg", "9621.jpg", 
"9331.jpg", "8370.jpg", "2345.jpg", "1463.jpg", "9830.jpg", "6550.jpg", 
"4621.jpg", "2214.jpg", "7020.jpg", "7050.jpg", "8090.jpg", "4640.jpg", 
"2208.jpg", "9495.jpg", "6243.jpg", "6510.jpg", "1722.jpg", "7430.jpg", 
"8210.jpg"), V11 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), V12 = c(2830.68310042, 2846.98065809, 2859.37971014, 2874.17664546, 
2890.27404476, 2903.86361556, 2917.43595781, 2933.51306339, 2948.51269093, 
2960.7119709, 2976.80791512, 2989.90620453, 3003.978659, 3020.04446973, 
3033.92808172, 3047.22799153, 3063.32629306, 3076.0237729, 3090.50472677, 
3106.57706668, 3120.94306028, 3133.72735545, 3149.82645618, 3162.62568556, 
3177.02317877, 3193.10291246, 3206.70018629, 3220.2760208, 3236.35869546, 
3250.55899136, 3263.55684183, 3279.65437676, 3294.43550569, 3306.81603279, 
3322.89098268, 3337.89114651, 3350.090125, 3366.18892521, 3379.88625864, 
3393.36636756, 3409.45657284, 3421.92863112), V13 = c(2835.69763893, 
2848.29687672, 2863.09567871, 2879.19290698, 2892.79072679, 2906.37089299, 
2922.44575069, 2937.4291307, 2949.62896786, 2965.72728909, 2978.8255204, 
2992.92205676, 3008.98648165, 3022.86163324, 3036.14441549, 3052.24415537, 
3064.94277449, 3079.44004982, 3095.51054223, 3109.88410692, 3122.66037352, 
3138.74359936, 3151.54372264, 3165.94112343, 3182.03895063, 3195.60906279, 
3209.20861148, 3225.29223025, 3239.47566646, 3252.47514977, 3268.5729521, 
3283.37067313, 3295.75078474, 3311.82475409, 3326.80706441, 3339.0077946, 
3355.10713238, 3368.80466196, 3382.30225456, 3398.38243168, 3410.86352153, 
3425.53895182), V14 = c(2836.94777244, 2849.34692278, 2864.14559232, 
2880.24285764, 2893.84690476, 2907.41310083, 2923.48541492, 2938.47947031, 
2950.67996483, 2966.77708896, 2979.87464765, 2993.96235442, 3010.02878474, 
3023.90025773, 3037.19497426, 3053.294102, 3065.99249573, 3080.48936393, 
3096.55416056, 3110.92728376, 3123.69894418, 3139.79323721, 3152.59289875, 
3166.99070677, 3183.08791861, 3196.65164933, 3210.2491143, 3226.33053225, 
3240.525598, 3253.52515929, 3269.62254874, 3284.42027478, 3296.79053404, 
3312.87457863, 3327.85804343, 3340.05716338, 3356.1565393, 3369.85474886, 
3383.33959784, 3399.43583915, 3411.90666723, 3426.57683964), 
    V15 = c(2842.96401751, 2855.36415856, 2870.16104373, 2886.25808632, 
    2899.8555051, 2913.42098007, 2929.49642383, 2944.49579289, 
    2956.69520627, 2972.7931764, 2985.88998124, 2999.97137667, 
    3016.03538767, 3029.91100089, 3043.21125712, 3059.30987528, 
    3072.00781376, 3086.49361198, 3102.56072439, 3116.93394175, 
    3129.71012547, 3145.80991423, 3158.6092781, 3173.00704328, 
    3189.0933848, 3202.68998311, 3216.25919269, 3232.34262987, 
    3246.54154305, 3259.54142981, 3275.63775768, 3290.42459499, 
    3302.7999622, 3318.8800581, 3333.87431569, 3346.07443061, 
    3362.1727909, 3375.87039741, 3389.35076625, 3405.4480156, 
    3417.91193105, 3432.58903452), V16 = c(2.27239183, 1.46103891, 
    1.11921971, 1.29976657, 1.49725865, 0.99838504, 1.80190757, 
    1.2957642, 1.8833041, 1.18930539, 1.91855918, 2.26358663, 
    1.44166371, 0.81771426, 1.87301313, 1.17165941, 1.40796688, 
    1.00468407, 1.47894186, 0.65129485, 1.00474347, 1.42280495, 
    0.94366453, 1.13311729, 1.08187487, 1.23435578, 1.01662371, 
    1.35480372, 1.05198223, 2.20586125, 0.6957003, 0.78074666, 
    1.77468312, 1.82572998, 1.82731178, 1.19673552, 1.50809555, 
    1.3260996, 1.57415788, 2.13057779, 1.61226701, 1.33258129
    ), V17 = c(5, 1.3, 3.7, 5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 3.9, 1.1, 5, 2, 3, 
    5, 2.8, 2.2, 5, 1.6, 3.4, 5, 3.3, 1.7, 5, 1.7, 3.3, 5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 5, 3.1, 1.9, 5, 3.7, 1.3, 5, 3.9, 1.1, 5, 2.6, 2.4, 
    5, 1.4, 3.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L
)), structure(list(V1 = c(5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 
5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 
5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 
5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 
5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 5003L, 
5003L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L), V7 = 1:42, V8 = c("D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", 
"I", "D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", 
"D", "D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I", "V", "V", "V", "D", 
"D", "D", "V", "V", "V", "I", "I", "I"), V9 = c("P", "P", "P", 
"N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "T", "T", "T", "N", 
"N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", 
"N", "T", "T", "T", "P", "P", "P", "N", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P"
), V10 = c("4659.jpg", "8185.jpg", "5450.jpg", "9500.jpg", "6370.jpg", 
"6210.jpg", "5660.jpg", "4623.jpg", "5260.jpg", "2692.jpg", "7361.jpg", 
"6311.jpg", "7175.jpg", "2890.jpg", "7004.jpg", "2715.jpg", "9470.jpg", 
"9415.jpg", "7400.jpg", "8400.jpg", "2346.jpg", "6315.jpg", "9520.jpg", 
"9265.jpg", "8350.jpg", "4614.jpg", "1620.jpg", "9600.jpg", "6260.jpg", 
"2753.jpg", "2381.jpg", "2493.jpg", "6150.jpg", "7270.jpg", "4652.jpg", 
"2341.jpg", "9452.jpg", "3300.jpg", "6244.jpg", "2331.jpg", "5811.jpg", 
"8080.jpg"), V11 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), V12 = c(1778.39814779, 1794.66955017, 1807.05304984, 1820.85258368, 
1836.95167276, 1850.56601201, 1863.1644145, 1879.24465175, 1894.21750028, 
1905.38431034, 1921.48437907, 1934.58453319, 1947.68174495, 1963.77891255, 
1977.65003662, 1989.92421098, 2005.99994814, 2018.68249564, 2032.18262005, 
2048.28013671, 2062.67831834, 2074.47566186, 2090.53996975, 2103.31568701, 
2116.71444193, 2132.8307998, 2146.43692569, 2159.0270518, 2175.11474787, 
2189.27217003, 2201.27996151, 2217.34932513, 2232.14614334, 2243.54524832, 
2259.64186742, 2274.61238405, 2285.78740174, 2301.85075916, 2315.52905518, 
2328.01429283, 2344.10999375, 2356.60846788), V13 = c(1783.41158352, 
1795.98600743, 1809.76883376, 1825.86920575, 1839.46897359, 1852.08223555, 
1868.17934805, 1883.15087696, 1894.32458202, 1910.40056956, 1923.50095396, 
1936.60073834, 1952.6980521, 1966.5953863, 1978.85978513, 1994.93266113, 
2007.61650661, 2021.09947094, 2037.19887631, 2051.59635269, 2063.39423195, 
2079.48183718, 2092.24855148, 2105.63167585, 2121.73130758, 2135.34794412, 
2147.9454085, 2164.04274244, 2178.22329608, 2190.18059593, 2206.29698602, 
2221.06337408, 2232.46304901, 2248.56140823, 2263.55890974, 2274.72298869, 
2290.79597905, 2304.46236276, 2316.94521006, 2333.02830625, 2345.52714998, 
2359.23146548), V14 = c(1784.65284278, 1797.03647351, 1810.81873264, 
1826.91933961, 1840.53464514, 1853.13297127, 1869.22961427, 1884.1941818, 
1895.36766193, 1911.45056078, 1924.55096298, 1937.65044915, 1953.74818115, 
1967.6336646, 1979.89975464, 1995.97256449, 2008.65396355, 2022.1499575, 
2038.24986552, 2052.64690288, 2064.44493158, 2080.52499275, 2093.28930834, 
2106.68226018, 2122.78167243, 2136.39762533, 2148.99542426, 2165.0926221, 
2179.25732171, 2191.25021477, 2207.33456886, 2222.11312128, 2233.51318712, 
2249.61074977, 2264.59571618, 2275.77297399, 2291.83606674, 2305.50074661, 
2317.9812663, 2334.07857459, 2346.57703731, 2360.27479414), V15 = c(1790.66065182, 
1803.04183667, 1816.83597302, 1832.93579409, 1846.55080328, 1859.14829024, 
1875.235072, 1890.20088982, 1901.37397943, 1917.46795723, 1930.56708003, 
1943.6657331, 1959.76355729, 1973.64344119, 1985.90769956, 2001.98365794, 
2014.66629685, 2028.16601121, 2044.26453256, 2058.66229876, 2070.46107834, 
2086.53145683, 2099.29901093, 2112.69831484, 2128.81096062, 2142.4138868, 
2155.01166613, 2171.09680187, 2185.26431756, 2197.26342651, 2213.34656808, 
2228.13022975, 2239.52926994, 2255.62701449, 2270.60771614, 2281.7796938, 
2297.84619268, 2311.51158522, 2323.99521848, 2340.09452581, 2352.59196262, 
2366.28997997), V16 = c(4.00061554, 1.8774984, 1.943505, 3.39527626, 
2.00290151, 2.26146808, 1.168004, 3.17210792, 3.21362597, 4.00228237, 
2.89042446, 3.90804253, 3.80087994, 3.0794306, 2.0969269, 4.00193167, 
3.78258696, 3.40912195, 3.91980072, 3.9490749, 3.89213988, 4.00200561, 
3.99941022, 3.96590426, 2.49138412, 3.99906077, 3.99919385, 2.28047369, 
3.76505293, 3.90544913, 3.9988001, 3.05481067, 3.95526409, 3.89273008, 
3.99936508, 3.70160298, 3.88020859, 3.23017589, 2.63215948, 3.99974673, 
4.00203896, 2.95468224), V17 = c(5, 1.3, 2.7, 5, 2.5, 1.5, 5, 
3.9, 0.1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2.8, 1.2, 5, 1.6, 2.4, 5, 3.3, 0.7, 5, 
1.7, 2.3, 5, 2.5, 1.5, 5, 3.1, 0.9, 5, 3.7, 0.3, 5, 3.9, 0.1, 
5, 2.6, 1.4, 5, 1.4, 2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L)))
```

The filenames for each data list is:

```
filelist[1:3]
[1] "C:/Users/Desktop/ER_raw_data/output_subject5001_prepost1_run1.txt"
[2] "C:/Users/Desktop/ER_raw_data/output_subject5002_prepost1_run1.txt"
[3] "C:/Users/Desktop/ER_raw_data/output_subject5004_prepost1_run1.txt"
```

I can extract the subject ID from the filename with the following:

```
IDs <- unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(filelist), "[^0-9]+")))))[2]
```

Like the third filename, some filenames have different subject IDs than the data within the first column of the corresponding list. I am struggling now to replace the list column1 IDs, with the **filename ID** corresponding to that list.

I know I can use the `replace` function, but I am not sure how to *avoid* a for loop for the 100+ ID extractions and replacements. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use the following solution:

```
IDs <- gsub(".*subject(\\d+).*", "\\1", filename, perl = TRUE)

Map(function(x, y) {
  x[["V1"]] <- y
  x
}, df, IDs)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. We could ouse `parse_number` from `readr` to get the ID's
2. Create a `tibble` of each df in the list
3. Use `map2` from `purrr` package to iterate over each tibble and `mutate` `V1`

```
library(tidyverse)
new_filelist <- as.list(parse_number(filelist))

my_list <- map(my_list, as_tibble)

map2(my_list, new_filelist, ~ mutate(., V1 =.y))
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 42 x 17
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 V8    V9    V10       V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  5001     1     1     1     0     1     1 D     P     5480.j~     1 1987. 1993. 1994. 2000. 1.98    5  
 2  5001     1     1     1     0     1     2 D     P     8186.j~     1 2004. 2005. 2006. 2012. 1.22    1.3
 3  5001     1     1     1     0     1     3 D     P     5621.j~     1 2016. 2019. 2020. 2026. 1.07    2.7
 4  5001     1     1     1     0     2     4 V     N     9471.j~     1 2030. 2035. 2036. 2042. 0.975   5  
 5  5001     1     1     1     0     2     5 V     N     9007.j~     1 2046. 2049. 2050. 2056. 1.01    2.5
 6  5001     1     1     1     0     2     6 V     N     6555.j~     1 2060. 2061. 2062. 2068. 2.27    1.5
 7  5001     1     1     1     0     3     7 I     P     7280.j~     2 2072. 2077. 2078. 2084. 1.69    5  
 8  5001     1     1     1     0     3     8 I     P     4622.j~     3 2088. 2092. 2093. 2099. 1.51    3.9
 9  5001     1     1     1     0     3     9 I     P     5594.j~     3 2103. 2103. 2105. 2111. 0.947   0.1
10  5001     1     1     1     0     4    10 D     N     2688.j~     2 2115. 2120. 2121. 2127. 1.93    5  
# ... with 32 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 42 x 17
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 V8    V9    V10       V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  5002     1     1     0     1     1     1 D     P     4680.j~     2 2831. 2836. 2837. 2843. 2.27    5  
 2  5002     1     1     0     1     1     2 D     P     8341.j~     2 2847. 2848. 2849. 2855. 1.46    1.3
 3  5002     1     1     0     1     1     3 D     P     5820.j~     3 2859. 2863. 2864. 2870. 1.12    3.7
 4  5002     1     1     0     1     2     4 V     N     9620.j~     2 2874. 2879. 2880. 2886. 1.30    5  
 5  5002     1     1     0     1     2     5 V     N     9042.j~     3 2890. 2893. 2894. 2900. 1.50    2.5
 6  5002     1     1     0     1     2     6 V     N     6250.j~     2 2904. 2906. 2907. 2913. 0.998   2.5
 7  5002     1     1     0     1     3     7 I     P     7260.j~     2 2917. 2922. 2923. 2929. 1.80    5  
 8  5002     1     1     0     1     3     8 I     P     4607.j~     3 2934. 2937. 2938. 2944. 1.30    3.9
 9  5002     1     1     0     1     3     9 I     P     5000.j~     2 2949. 2950. 2951. 2957. 1.88    1.1
10  5002     1     1     0     1     4    10 D     N     2053.j~     3 2961. 2966. 2967. 2973. 1.19    5  
# ... with 32 more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 42 x 17
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 V8    V9    V10       V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  5004     1     1     1     2     1     1 D     P     4659.j~     4 1778. 1783. 1785. 1791.  4.00   5  
 2  5004     1     1     1     2     1     2 D     P     8185.j~     3 1795. 1796. 1797. 1803.  1.88   1.3
 3  5004     1     1     1     2     1     3 D     P     5450.j~     3 1807. 1810. 1811. 1817.  1.94   2.7
 4  5004     1     1     1     2     2     4 V     N     9500.j~     3 1821. 1826. 1827. 1833.  3.40   5  
 5  5004     1     1     1     2     2     5 V     N     6370.j~     1 1837. 1839. 1841. 1847.  2.00   2.5
 6  5004     1     1     1     2     2     6 V     N     6210.j~     2 1851. 1852. 1853. 1859.  2.26   1.5
 7  5004     1     1     1     2     3     7 I     P     5660.j~     4 1863. 1868. 1869. 1875.  1.17   5  
 8  5004     1     1     1     2     3     8 I     P     4623.j~     3 1879. 1883. 1884. 1890.  3.17   3.9
 9  5004     1     1     1     2     3     9 I     P     5260.j~     3 1894. 1894. 1895. 1901.  3.21   0.1
10  5004     1     1     1     2     4    10 D     N     2692.j~     1 1905. 1910. 1911. 1917.  4.00   5  
# ... with 32 more rows
```

Comment: This also worked, but I saw the other answer first..

Comment: The other is better. And it is from "Mr. map" also known as Anoushiravan.  I learning 'map' from him!

Comment: @Shai That's not TRUE! My friend is being so kind. Both solutions are good at their own place :) and He was answering my qs when I didn't know what R is :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
ids <- str_extract(basename(filelist), '(?<=subject)\\d+')
map2(list1, ids, ~ .x %>%
        mutate(V1  = .y))
```

Comment: Also this answer from our master is brilliant!